# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on ReloadData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm loading data dynamically from an API using a `UISearchBar` and trying to display it, using something like this:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"Search Text: %@",[searchBar text]);
    [self startSearchingWithText:[searchBar text]];
}
- (void) startSearchingWithText:(NSString *)text {
    ...
    // Go through the list of services and set up a query for the search term
    QueryServiceManager *manager = [[QueryServiceManager alloc] initWithServices: services];

    // Set up the query
    if (![manager addKeyword: text])
        NSLog(@"PROBLEM!");

    // Execute the query and store the titles in an array
    self.data = [[manager makeQuery] copy]; // Returns a NSArray

    NSLog(@"%@",self.data);

    // Add the items to the tableView

    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

My `UITableViewController` code is set up to read from self.data, which is initially a `NSArray` of `@""` elements, as such:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    [self.data count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Set up the cell...

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

All I get when I do this is:

> (gdb) continue
>   2010-02-26 18:43:32.515 iSave[11690:207] (
>       "Toshiba Satellite L505-GS5037 TruBrite 15.6-Inch Laptop (Black)",
>       "Dell Inspiron 11 11.6-Inch Obsidian Black Laptop (Windows 7 Premium)",
>       "ASUS Eee PC Seashell 1005PE-MU17-BK 10.1-Inch Black Netbook - Up to 11 Hours of Battery Life",
>       "SwissGear Computer Backpack (Red)",
>       "Belkin 36-Piece Demagnatized Computer Tool Kit  with Case (Black)",
>       "Compaq EVO N610C",
>       "Belkin F8E062 55-Piece Computer Tool Kit with Black Case (Demagnetized Tools)",
>       "ASUS Eee PC Seashell 1005PE-PU17-BK 10.1-Inch Black Netbook - Up to 14 Hours of Battery Life",
>       "Harman Kardon SoundSticks II 2.1 Plug and Play Multimedia Speaker System",
>       "ION Audio VCR 2 PC USB VHS Video to Computer Converter"
>   )
>   (gdb) continue
>   Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
>   (gdb)

Any ideas? It looks like the `NSArray` is being populated properly, then things are failing on/after the reloadData call (breakpoints confirm this, but can't isolate where things are going wrong)

**EDIT**: I replaced the`NSLog()` with enumeration

```
for ( NSString *elem in self.data ) 
    NSLog(elem);
```

And it still crashes. I managed to coax a log out of it: http://pastebin.com/NDVKLsJC

When I remove the `NSLog()` entirely, it doesn't crash, but the `UITableView`doesn't update, either.

Comment: where are you calling reloadData?

Comment: Under the NSLog() command above. That function is called automatically when the "Search" button is hit. Post edited to show the full definition.

Comment: what does the log say usually there is a method that is causing the "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Comment: I pasted the gdb output above. There's no more information than that.

Comment: what about in the system console not the debug console? crash log report?

Comment: is it NSLog(@"%@",self.data); i thought you said self.data was an array? maybe try fast enumeration?

Comment: All the console says is the same as my NSLog(), minus the EXC_BAD_ACCESS; it comes up with a list of the items in self.data

Removing the NSLog() removes the EXC_BAD_ACCESS, but the table view doesn't refresh the data (it remains blank)

Comment: Managed to get a crash log: http://pastebin.com/NDVKLsJC (that's with fast enumeration being NSLog-ed)

Answer (score 4):

Have you identified the object which you're trying to access but which no longer exists, the object which is giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

If not then you should enable Zombies in your app, then you can issue a command to gdb which will tell you which object is causing the crash.

Answer (score 1):

Something weird:  You're saying that you only have 1 row in each section, yet you're using `indexPath.row` to index into your array?  One of those is wrong, and I'm guessing it's the first.  Usually if you're displaying an array (of *n* elements) in a `UITableView`, you have one section and *n* rows in that section, which means you'd use `[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` to retrieve the appropriate object.

If you want a separate section for each item in the array, then you say that you have *n* sections, and 1 row in each section, and then use `[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]` to retrieve the appropriate object.

Oh, and you're leaking memory all over the place.

Comment: Like the person below, I just have "return 1;" in there for testing purposes. I'll edit the code above to reflect that, and put the correct code ([self.data count]) in, but it's the same problem regardless.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.data count];
}
```

instead of always returning `1`.

Comment: That's not the problem; I have it returning 1 so that I can make sure it works without going through the whole process. If it works for 1, it'll be easier to get it to work for the whole array. I just edited the code to reflect the "proper" counting, but the same problem arises.

Answer (score 0):

Hit shift-command-b to analyze the project and solve all problems displayed (potential leaks, etc.)